# Can NDA-s be used to abuse the "Fruit of the poisonous tree" doctrine?

Tags: non-disclosure, hypothetical

Could non-disclosure agreements prevent criminals from snitching on each other, or to prevent legally obtaining proof of illegal operations?

I have two similar scenarios in mind:

1. A group of bank robbers sign NDA-s to each other, so that if one gets caught, their testimony will be inadmissible due to being "fruit of the poisonous tree".
2. An illegal gambling establishment signs an NDA with anyone who enters, so that any information gathered by law enforcement would be illegally obtained.

The question is: does the fruit of the poisonous tree doctrine extend this far, and are there any examples of criminals trying something similar?

Comment: How is law enforcement asking a person to break an NDA "breaking the law"?  And contracts to do illegal things are void.

Comment: Also https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/70232/is-there-some-kind-of-disclosure-immunity-if-you-violate-your-non-disclosure-agr is somewhat related.  Basically, such an NDA is almost certainly void as against public policy.  In some cases, there are statutes that explicitly forbid asking to sign an NDA that would prevent "whistleblowing" disclosure of illegal activity.

Comment: Re: "...are there any examples of criminals trying something similar?" there's always the ["*I'm gonna make him an offer he can't refuse*"](https://godfather.fandom.com/wiki/Vito_Corleone) option.

Comment: Another possibly relevant example is the Trump White House insisting that staff sign NDAs.