# Talking about a crime after a non-disclosure agreement

Tags: non-disclosure

Let's say I have this scenario.

**I commited a crime. No one has caught me yet.**

**Another person catches me. We agree to sign a non-disclosure agreement.**

**That person ends up speaking out about my crime.**

*Does this mean I will be investigated by some sort of government and sentenced if I was found guilty?*

OR

*Will my crime not be legally allowed to be investigated into unless another reason shows up of why the government should investigate.*

*Then what will happen to the person who spoke out?*

*This is all a scenario and just looking for the answer out of interest.*

Comment: Interesting question - however, it looks very similar to the one I linked as a duplicate. If you feel your question is different, please edit to explain the differences.

Comment: Also closely related: [When can an NDA be legally broken?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4339/when-can-an-nda-be-legally-broken)

Comment: You can absolutely still be prosecuted for that, an NDA isn't an immunity document. You can sue somebody for breaking the NDA, but the information leaked could still be used against you in almost every case.

Comment: Depending on the details and juisdiction you may also be able to lay a complaint of extortion.  Generally a (civil) agreement can't be used in the courts to shield you from criminal liability or to suppress evidence in a criminal matter.